# Show that the logaritmic primal barrier $B(x,\rho)$ is not bounded from above (for $x\in \Omega$) for any fixed $\rho>0$

Tags: optimization, upper-lower-bounds

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Consider the problem

$$\text{minimize}\quad \frac{1}{1+x^2}\quad\text{s.t}\quad  x\geq 1$$

Show that the logaritmic primal barrier $B(x,\rho)$ is not bounded from above (for $x\in \Omega$) for any fixed $\rho>0$

My try:

I checked and the limit of $B$ when $x$ goes to infinity is infinity

Now,
let

$\quad B(x,\rho)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\rho*log(x-1)\quad$ for $\quad\rho>0$,

Let's suppose that $B(x,\rho)$ is bounded from above. Then  there exists $b\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y<b$ for all $y \in B$.

This implies that $$\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\rho*log(x-1)< b$$

I don't see how to solve for $x$ here.

Any suggestions would be great!
I'm not sure if contradiction is the right way.

Comment: $\lim_{x \to \infty} B(x,\rho) = \infty$. The barrier function is a bit odd, usually it increases to $+\infty$ as one gets nearer to the barrier ($x=1$).